# How to fix javascript error in application using IWebBrowser2?

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, iwebbrowser2

I have a C++ aplication that is using the IWebBrowser2 interface for rendering some online html pages.
The problem is that when accesing a certain link I receive a javascript error, although if I am accesing that same page using Internet Explorer, the page loads with no error.
The recived error in my application is "Object doesn't support this action"

I was able to hide the error by using the put_Silent() method and setting it to VARIANT_TRUE, but this is not a solution as the content displayed is not correct.

I know that IWebBrowser2 is using the Internet Explorer engine to load the pages, so I guess that there is a way to fix this problem as the page loads ok in IE.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers and look if they give the same error?

Comment: You can use Javascript debugger in IE to see what exactly code is failing.

Comment: The page I'm loading is not created by me. I don't want to fix the html (if it has any problems). I just want to have the same behavior in my app as in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to implement [IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> When your application hosts the browser control, you can replace the
>   Windows Internet Explorer message box caption (which is used for
>   Microsoft JScript alerts among other things) with a custom caption

I think you would want to return S_FALSE.

> S_FALSE   Host did not display its UI. MSHTML displays its message box.