# Disabling "Script Error" popup IWebBrowser2 c++ WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, com, iwebbrowser2

Having a HWND with IWebBrowser2 on it. IWebBrowser2 is new CLSID_WEBBROWSER.
When I navigating to youtube,google and etc, sometimes it shows me Script Error. And I want to disable it. How can I do it?

```cpp
if (MoneyHWND == NULL) {
                if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL)))
                {
                    vector<wchar_t> fn(1000);
                    GetModuleFileName(0, fn.data(), 1000);
                    PathStripPath(fn.data());
                    RKEY k(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
                    k[fn.data()] = 11001UL; // Use IE 11
                    MoneyHWND = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FORMVIEW1), hWnd, MoneyProc);
                    pBrowser2 = new WebBrowser(MoneyHWND);

                    RECT rc;
                    GetClientRect(MoneyHWND, &rc);
                    pBrowser2->SetRect(rc);


                    pBrowser2->Navigate(site);

                    OleUninitialize();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I know that I will edit it later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix javascript error in application using IWebBrowser2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642479/how-to-fix-javascript-error-in-application-using-iwebbrowser2)

Comment: inherit your `class WebBrowser` from `IDocHostShowUI` too. will be `ShowMessage` called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IWebBrowser2::Silent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752074(v=vs.85)):

> Sets or gets a value that indicates whether the object can display dialog boxes.

Note, that the property is exposed to C and C++ programs using the following signatures:

```cpp
HRESULT IWebBrowser2::get_Silent(VARIANT_BOOL *pbSilent);
HRESULT IWebBrowser2::put_Silent(VARIANT_BOOL bSilent);
```

In other words:

```cpp
    // ...
    auto hr{ pBrowser2->put_Silent(VARIANT_TRUE) };
    if FAILED(hr)
    {
        // Handle error
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: @TheGamerCoder - `class WebBrowser : ...public IDocHostShowUI`, in  `WebBrowser::QueryInterface` add `else if (riid == __uuidof(IDocHostShowUI)) { *ppvObject = static_cast<IDocHostShowUI*>(this); }` or `webBrowser2->put_Silent(VARIANT_TRUE)`